# How to add suffix to column names except some columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Given pandas DataFrame, how can I add the suffix "_old" to all columns except two columns `Id` and `Name`?

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1,'Alex',22,'single'],[2,'Bob',32,'married'],[3,'Clarke',23,'single']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Id','Name','Age','Status'])
```

Comment: @timgeb: Good point:) suffix!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can reassign the dataframe's columns:

```
>>> df
   Id    Name  Age   Status
0   1    Alex   22   single
1   2     Bob   32  married
2   3  Clarke   23   single
>>> 
>>> keep_same = {'Id', 'Name'}
>>> df.columns = ['{}{}'.format(c, '' if c in keep_same else '_old')
...:               for c in df.columns]
>>>
>>> df
   Id    Name  Age_old Status_old
0   1    Alex       22     single
1   2     Bob       32    married
2   3  Clarke       23     single
```

Comment: Hi! How might I be able to adapt this as a prefix, not suffix? Thanks so much!

Comment: I've actually posed this as a new question in case anyone else has the same one! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70311932/how-to-add-prefix-to-column-names-except-some-columns

Comment: This is a nice approach and would also work with an f-string `df.columns = [f"{c}{'' if c in keep_same else '_old'}" for c in df.columns]`

Answer (score 19):

You can use the [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method which takes a dictionary of `{column -> new_name}`:

```
df.rename(columns={c: c+'_old' for c in df.columns if c not in ['Id', 'Name']})
```

Answer (score 9):

Using `map`

```
df.columns=df.columns.map(lambda x : x+'_old' if x !='Id' and x!='Name' else x)
df
Out[181]: 
   Id    Name  Age_old Status_old
0   1    Alex       22     single
1   2     Bob       32    married
2   3  Clarke       23     single
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.rename(columns = lambda col: f"{col}_old" 
                                if col not in ('Name', 'Id') 
                                else col
          )

   Id    Name  Age_old Status_old
0   1    Alex       22     single
1   2     Bob       32    married
2   3  Clarke       23     single
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use add_prefix or add_suffix as you need. To skip renaming some columns, you can set them as indexes and reset index after renaming.

If you want to exclude "ID" from renaming and add prefix "pre_"

```
df.set_index(['ID']).add_prefix("pre_").reset_index()
```

Derived from wwnde's answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70311963/17674957

Answer (score -1):

Now, you can do this in pandas with df.add_suffix()

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).